# Select every first unique element by grouping

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have a list of elements which have alternating classes. The occurrences of the classes are random and can occur once or many times in a row.

I am looking a way to select every first occurrence of an element (marked with a `-`). Preferably, I'd like to do this in CSS but I can work with a JavaScript solution as well.

```
<div class="type-1"></div>  -
<div class="type-1"></div>
<div class="type-1"></div>
<div class="type-2"></div>  -
<div class="type-1"></div>  -
<div class="type-1"></div>
<div class="type-2"></div>  -
<div class="type-2"></div>
<div class="type-1"></div>  -
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like this: https://jsfiddle.net/aq8nw21f/

This code uses the CSS adjacent sibling selector, as well as :first-of-type to get the edge case of the first item in the list.

```css
#container > div:first-of-type, .type-1 + .type-2, .type-2 + .type-1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span>If you used :first-child, the div below this would not highlight.</span>
    <div class="type-1">Yes</div>
    <div class="type-1">No</div>
    <div class="type-1">No</div>
    <div class="type-2">Yes</div>
    <div class="type-1">Yes</div>
    <div class="type-1">No</div>
    <div class="type-2">Yes</div>
    <div class="type-2">No</div>
    <div class="type-1">Yes</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going crazy... at first I thought "since when does `:first-of-type` work on more than the first element of its type?" but then I realized what was going on. Quite simple.

Comment: @insertusernamehere please don't make purely stylistic edits to someone else's code, especially when those edits harm readability

Comment: @TylerH I made this edit explicitly to *increase readability*. You can spot all the selectors involved and their differences more easily when they are on multiple lines … But of course you can see this another way.

Comment: You don't need the 1st of type, just mark the 1st element automatically.

Comment: How would you mark the first element automatically in a more straightforward way than this?

Comment: `.type-1:first-child, .type-2:first-child` although it's not that big of a difference :)

Comment: Actually, `:first-child` would be assuming that the first div is the first child element in it's parent container. We can't make that assumption so `:first-of-type` is more appropriate.

Comment: Actually, since they're all divs, and `nth-*` selectors look at the DOM not the CSS (i.e., classes are ignored), only `div:first-child` makes sense.

Comment: @OriDrori, well I'm only talking about the code structure posted above. If there were other divs in the app, we simply need a complex selector (i.e,, `#container div:first-child`).

Comment: Thanks @TW80000 This helped my find the solution I was looking for https://jsfiddle.net/rep7ctza/1/

Comment: @Sebastien, only the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) in your fiddle is working as intended. See my comment above. Your compounded class and `:first-of-type` selector is not doing much: https://jsfiddle.net/rep7ctza/2/

Comment: @Michael_B is right about not being able to use classes. It seemed to work even though it shouldn't have, but I changed it anyway.

Comment: @TylerH: You are right, the use of :first-of-type by itself is potentially misleading here. :first-child is very much preferred if every child element is going to be a div (or otherwise all of the same element type). If there are going to be children of differing types, I consider it best practice to at least qualify the :first-of-type with a type selector (as has now been done), unless you have a very good reason to use the universal selector (and no, performance is not it).

Comment: @TW80000: You can't assume that the first element with these classes is the first child, yet you can assume that only elements with these classes are divs and any preceding siblings, should they occur, will never be of the same type? I don't follow.

Comment: (I see that @Michael_B has demonstrated my point. It pays to click fiddle URLs once in a while...)

Answer (score 0):

And a less spectacular JS solution than the CSS one of TW80000:

```js
var els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="type-"]'));

console.log(els.filter(function(el, index) {
  return index === 0 || !el.classList.contains(els[index - 1].classList.item(0));
}));
```

```html
<div class="type-1">1</div>
<div class="type-1">2</div>
<div class="type-1">3</div>
<div class="type-2">4</div>
<div class="type-1">5</div>
<div class="type-1">6</div>
<div class="type-2">7</div>
<div class="type-2">8</div>
<div class="type-1">9</div>
```

Comment: Cool solution, but encouraging JS solutions for what can be done in CSS seems fairly bad practice, unless this solves some sort of cross browser compatibility issues? :)

Comment: It doesn't. The CSS solution is much better. The only uses I can think of are those that CSS can't actually do, such as adding content or event handlers to the nodes, etc...